# Problem with adding values to insert on trigger MySQL (Error 1193 unknown system variable)

Tags: mysql, triggers, set

I have a table with sensor data and a table that gets data from an app.
Every time the app saves data to it's table, it saves two datetime values to "start time" and "end time" columns. Based on that time gap, I have to get some values from the sensor data table (start temp, maximum temp, max humidity...).

I am currently using a before insert trigger and using new.colName = (select from sensor ...).
First column inserts fine but after that I get "Error Code: 1193 Unknown system variable 'NEW.max_temp'".

Im sure this is because i have something wrong in my trigger syntax, but I am not able to determine what is causing this.

The values im filling are originally Null when the app inserts it's data and the columns exist im trying to SET NEW.XXXX exist.

My Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `Cegasa`.`FAB_BEFORE_INSERT`
BEFORE INSERT ON `fabrication`
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.start_temp = (SELECT temp FROM sensors WHERE (NEW.fab_start_date) <= date ORDER BY date LIMIT 1);
SET NEW.max_temp = (SELECT temp  FROM sensors WHERE (NEW.fab_end_date) >= date ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1);

DELIMITER;
```

First SET statement works fine but second one gives the error. I can provide further table structure if necessary but I think it has more to do with my syntax.

Comment: BEGIN-END needed.

Comment: @Akina I should enclose the SET statements after FOR EACH with them right?